# How to link .as Files to Main.as and Scenes in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to Actionscript 3 and coding, and just learning OOP. I am trying to move all my timeline code into Document Class. But i have build the app in different scenes, I am wondering if it is possible to link/add the .as files into Main.as then link the .as files to the different Scenes accordingly?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Generally in as3 you would create a Document Class which is a class similar to Main.as. After that you would use seperate .as files to describe other classes to be used within the Main.as class.

Comment: @Glitcher Yup i have created the Document Class as Main.as, and i did the import.com.name.asfile, but i can not seem to link that to the scenes. Because i created app with maybe 5 or 6 different scenes, and each scene has a few button, and textinput. Not sure how i connect, for example MouseEvent.Click from 1 as file to 1 button in a specific Scene, if you get what i mean. Sorry that if it sounds not very clear, i am very new to this.

Comment: @Clarklight I hope you didn't put too much work into setting up the scenes. Scenes are a pretty old school way of separating content which was helpful in the past for flash animations, but the feature isn't hat helpful when doing OOP/AS3. Try to move your scenes into individual MovieClips (e.g. edit multiple frames > copy frames > new movie clip > paste frames). These scene movie clips can either be nested instead a main one and have instane names or you can simply leave them in the library but export them for Actionscript(setup linkage so you can instiate the programmatically). HTH

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks for the advice, my scenes file are PSD that i did for the app, i tried to learn to save them as Movieclip before, but i also ran into difficulties again when i tried that. As i am not very sure how to import PSD into Stage then save the whole PSD as a movieclip, as there are 2-3 buttons,a few textinput etc. Can you give me some advice? Thanks so much

Comment: Flash does a decent job import psd files, but it's also important to make your life easier by configuring the import: for example convert layers to MovieClip symbols if you need them and name them as well. Not everything you can design in Photoshop has an equivalent in Flash so some complex graphics might need to be flattened as an image. Filters parameters need to be checked (values might be off), etc. I recommend importing a flattened version of the psd as reference, then importing again as layers/movieclips/etc. and making sure everything looks right. then fix masks/pivots/etc.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks so much for the advice, i just tried that and did some more further research. Just learned Nested Animation, i believe, i should convert all object within the stage from PSD to movieclips then hightlight all the movieclips and save that as 1 nested movieclip, i assume, then i can just save that 1 nested Movieclip in Lib, and then use .as File and pull that specific movieclip when i need?